# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined Angular Firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

** Cannot read property 'push' of undefined Angular Firebase**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl,FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList} from 'angularfire2/database';
@Injectable()
export class QuestionService {

  constructor(private firebase: AngularFireDatabase) { }
  questionList:AngularFireList<any>;


  form = new FormGroup({
    $key: new FormControl(null),
    newQuestion: new FormControl('', Validators.required)

  });

  getQuestions(){
    this.questionList = this.firebase.list('questions');
    return this.questionList.snapshotChanges();
  }

  insertQuestion(question){
    this.questionList.push({
      newQuestion: question.newQuestion
    });
  }

}
```

Trying to push data to firebase but encountering this error.

Comment: you are not initialized. that's why it happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just initialize your list

```
questionList:AngularFireList<any> = []
```