# Getting undefined push error when saving angular form to Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular-reactive-forms

Getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined in my Service when trying to save my Angular form. [image: Error Snapshot]

This is how i am trying to implement it in my article.service.ts

```
createArticle(data: ArticleDB) {
    this.articles.push(data);
}
```

tried [Stackoverflow reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52764494/cannot-read-property-push-of-undefined-angular-firebase) but it says Type 'undefined[]' is missing the following properties from type 'AngularFireList': query, valueChanges, snapshotChanges, stateChanges, and 4 more.
[Refrence image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSp0a.png)

Comment: `this.articles` is not an array, you should check this

Comment: set default value as `[]` i.e ( `empty array` )

Comment: Okay, I guess I don't have the knowledge to answer your question. Deleting it!

Comment: hey @xyz thanks for your efforts...